# Calling json data from an api

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from an api and use it to populate the div with the ID "output". I get an error that the $ is undefined. Can anyone help determine what I am missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta name="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

<div id="fullscreen">
<div id="output">

</div>

</div>

</body>
<script>
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "https://apiurl.com",
dataType: "json",
crossDomain: true,
success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
        var id = response[0];       
        var vname = response[1];
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: When you want to use a lib in the browser, you should include the `<script>` tag to load it ...

Comment: Hi. `$.ajax` is a [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) method. So, in order to make this code work, you should first add jQuery lib to your page. Try adding a script tag like this (can be above your existing script tag): `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`.  Another thing: put all your script tags at the end of `body` tag, but inside of it (you're using outside).

Answer (score 2):

As Sirko already explained in the comments, you are trying to use the javascript library JQuery, but the library is not available because you didn't include it.

You can include it by either downloading JQuery [here](http://jquery.com/download/) and including it via

```
<script src="src_to_local_jquery.js"/>
```

or by including it externally (described in CDN section of above link)

Also note, that script tags should be put either in the head or the body section. To make sure your custom script is executed after the page is ready, you can use [JQuery's document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) method.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` sign is not part of the JavaScript language, it is a short hand for a third party library jQuery (`$ === jQuery`).

You need to add it as a dependency in your html file with a script tag with a src attribute containing the URI for the source file before you can use it.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    ...
    ...
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(function () {
         // Your code here
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `jQuery` either as a [CDN](http://jquery.com/download/) or download add reference locally. Then make sure the DOM is ready before you make the call. You can read more about that [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
<script src="local_jquery.js"/>
// OR
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>


$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://apiurl.com",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
        var id = response[0];       
        var vname = response[1];
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);
    }
   });
});
```